# How can I set the index fill factor back to server default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, fill-factor

I have some indexes that I was playing with on my dev server.  I set the fill factor of these indexes using the following command:

```
alter index all on dbo.Table
rebuild with (fillfactor=80)
```

That sets and rebuilds all of the index on dbo.Table.  Now what I want is to set the fillfactor **back to the default of the server**.  IE, at the server level all indexes are set to have a fillfactor of 95.  I want the indexes to use the server default again, not just have the fill factor set to 95.

The reason I want to do this is so that, if I script this index and move it to a new server, it will use the default fill factor of that server rather than the specified 95.

Comment: ref: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Database-Maintenance-Best-Practices-Part-II-e28093-the-most-important-setting-FILLFACTOR.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through testing, it seems as though to get back to the default fillfactor on an index you need to drop and recreate it.  When you do an `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD`, any unspecified parameters will remain the same in the index's metadata unless otherwise explicitly changed in the `ALTER INDEX` command.

```
drop index IX_YourIndex
on YourTable
go

create index IX_YourIndex
on YourTable(YourKeyColumn)
go
```

To verify this:

```
select
    name,
    fill_factor
from testdb.sys.indexes
where name = 'IX_YourIndex'
```

`fill_factor` should be set to `0` to denote that it is using the instance's default value.  *(Note: 0 is for the default value, even if the instance configured fill factor is set to 95)*

Comment: Weird.  I right-clicked - script- drop and recreated the index, removed the fillfactor line and executed, and it's now specifying 95 for the fillfactor (same as the server).

Comment: Also, went into designer, removed the pk, saved, then readded the pk, same thing.

Comment: That's how I thought it was supposed to work, but also seeing some oddities here.

Comment: @DForck42 I can't recreate that behavior.